# How to find whether the app is called by "Share-Via"?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity

I have added my Android app to the "Share-Via" window. Following code is added to the `onCreate()` method of my code.

```
        if(getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND))
        {
            String text = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            textField.setText(text);
        }
```

Now the issues is, if this app activity get called from the share-via, it works. But if it get called directly (user opens the app -> go to that activity) this crashes with `NullPointerException`. I am getting `NullPointerException` right in here

```
if(getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND))
```

Following is how this Share-Via configured in the manifest file.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.xx.xx.xx"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: `if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(getIntent().getAction()) {`?

Comment: Of course that doesn't protect against `getIntent` being `null`, only for `getAction`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either `getIntent()` or `getAction()` is returning `null`.
You need to check for that.